# Create new entry if not empty and no duplicates exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a note with a title and a text if

- the title is not empty
- the title does not already exist

When I check for duplicates in my array, it always returns true, even if there are duplicates.

My code:

```
CreateNote(title, text){
    if (title.length > 0 && // title is empty?
 $.inArray(title, this.store.notes) < 0) // check the array for duplicates, returns always true, even with duplicates in the store
      this.store.AddNote(new Note(title, text));
  }
```

So what is wrong with the second check =?

Thanks

Comment: We need more information here. What is held in `this.store.notes`? If it's an object, there's your problem

Comment: in this store i keep the notes with the properties "title" and "text", means an object, yes

Comment: You cannot compare objects directly in JS, only their properties. See @RobbyCornelissen's answer

Answer (score 1):

You're not comparing the title to the other note titles, but instead to the note objects.

Assuming that the title is exposed as a `title` property on the note objects, you'd have to rewrite your condition like this:

```
$.inArray(title, this.store.notes.map(n => n.title)) < 0
```

Or with standard JavsScript:

```
!this.store.notes.some(n => n.title === title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value in {console.log($.inArray(title, this.store.notes))}.
or use other way of condition $.inArray(title, this.store.notes) === -1.
Hope this might solve the issue.